# SELECT statement returning incorrect results when executed from stored procedure, but works ok when tested independently

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Any guess what could be wrong with the `SELECT` statement shown below; it returns null when tested from a stored procedure (no issues with the inputs), but the test passes when executed independently.

```
SELECT 
    @JunitSlugs = ISNULL(@JunitSlugs, '') + ',' + JunitSlug + '-' +
                  (SELECT LookupValue
                   FROM Lookup
                   WHERE LookupId = JunitTypeId)
FROM 
    JunitList
WHERE 
    JunitId IN (SELECT JunitId
                FROM CapsuleJunits
                WHERE CapsuleId = @CapsuleId)
```

I am not a SQL expert, but I know there can be a better way of writing above SQL statement. Please suggest.

**BELOW COMPLETE PROC**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CapsuleList_GetReadyToPub] (@xmlDoc XML = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @CapsuleId INT
        DECLARE @PublicationIds VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @JunitSlugs VARCHAR(MAX)

        IF @xmlDoc IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @CapsuleId = c.value('(CapsuleId)[1]', 'INT')
                ,@PublicationIds = c.value('(PublicationIds)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)')
            FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('MCapsuleList') AS T(C)
        END

        BEGIN
            SELECT @JunitSlugs = ISNULL(@JunitSlugs, '') + ',' + JunitSlug + '-' + (
                    SELECT LookupValue
                    FROM Lookup
                    WHERE LookupId = JunitTypeId
                    )
            FROM JunitList
            WHERE JunitId IN (
                    SELECT JunitId
                    FROM CapsuleJunits
                    WHERE CapsuleId = 211
                    )

            --SELECT @JunitSlugs = ISNULL(@JunitSlugs, '') + ',' + JunitSlug + '-' + (SELECT LookupValue FROM Lookup WHERE LookupId = JunitTypeId) FROM JunitList WHERE JunitId IN ( SELECT JunitId FROM CapsuleJunits WHERE CapsuleId = @CapsuleId)
            SELECT @JunitSlugs = ISNULL(@JunitSlugs, '') + ',' + jl.JunitSlug + '-' + lu.LookupValue
            FROM JunitList jl
            INNER JOIN Lookup lu ON jl.JunitTypeID = lu.LookupID
            WHERE jl.JunitId IN (
                    SELECT JunitId
                    FROM CapsuleJunits
                    WHERE CapsuleId = @CapsuleId
                    )

            SELECT (
                    SELECT CL.[CapsuleId]
                        ,[PublicationIds]
                        ,[CapsuleSlug] AS Slug
                        ,@JunitSlugs AS JunitIds
                        --,CreatedBy    
                        ,[Headline] AS HeadLine
                        --,[Excerpt]    
                        --,[Correction]           
                        ,CL.UpdatedOn AS UpdatedOn
                    FROM CapsuleList CL
                    --LEFT JOIN [PublishUrls] PU ON PU.ParentId = CL.CapsuleId    
                    WHERE CL.PublicationIds = @PublicationIds
                        AND CL.CapsuleStatusId = 53
                    ORDER BY CL.CapsuleId
                    FOR XML PATH('CapsuleList')
                        ,TYPE
                    )
            FOR XML PATH('CapsuleLists')
                ,ROOT('CapsuleListInfoByXml')
        END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ReturnedErrorID INT

        EXECUTE @ReturnedErrorID = dbo.usp_HandleException
    END CATCH

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as changing the SQL statement, you could do this (using a variety of [JOINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)):

```
SELECT @JunitSlugs = ISNULL(@JunitSlugs, '') + ',' + jl.JunitSlug + '-' + lu.LookupValue
FROM JunitList jl
INNER JOIN Lookup lu ON jl.JunitTypeID = lu.LookupID
WHERE jl.JunitId IN (SELECT JunitId
                     FROM CapsuleJunits
                     WHERE CapsuleId = @CapsuleId)
```

---

In comments we've discussed that your `SELECT` outside of the stored procedure is returning value, so I've removed the part of my answer about checking for `NULL`. I've also removed a part about whether you are using an `OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure since you've recently posted what your stored procedure looks like. Possibly the question on the stored procedure should be its own separate question since it involves much more than just the initial query posted in the original question.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am also curious to know what is wrong with my SELECT statement

Comment: Are you returning the value of `@JunitSlugs` in your stored procedure? I mean, between the two options you mention, the non-stored procedure execution just assigns the value to `@JunitSlugs`, so you've got to PRINT it, or SELECT it to see it, but is it doing the same in your stored procedure? Also possible that `@CapsuleId` is null (or just being set to something that wont be found in your query... aka.. jl.JunitID has nothing to match on from CapsuleJunits where CapsuleId = `@CapsuleId`) because its not being set in the stored procedure.. could be quite a few things

Comment: When tested independently there is no variable @JunitSlugs instead confirming the result without variable assignment but I guess that shouldn't be a difference, when added the same variable assignment to the SQL statement which you suggested it worked perfectly.

Comment: Nope @CapsuleId is not null

Comment: @Naga Ok so a little confused here, but at the end of your stored procedure execute `SELECT @JunitSlugs`. Also do the same in your independent query. Are the results the same now? I feel like what I am reading is the your independent query does not assign to a variable, you are just purely doing a SELECT, which would give you a result if there was one (which is sounds like there is), but in your stored procedure, you are assigning to the variable `@JunitSlugs`, but that in itself isn't enough to return the value. You've got to return that value, which could be achieved by `SELECT @JunitSlugs`

Comment: Thanks for your time, I posted complete proc at the end of question please check you can find the SQL which you suggested worked whereas my SQL did not work

Comment: Hi @Naga, I've updated my answer again, however it seems this might keep going around and around. Could you please consider asking your question about the stored procedure as a separate question? The difficulty in pairing these questions is that the query posted in the beginning only represents a small portion of the stored procedure, so its very likely that the single query is perfectly fine, but its 1,2,3 other things in the stored procedure that are causing a `NULL` return. If you made a stored procedure that does 100% exactly the same thing as your SELECT query, you should get same result.

Comment: Hi @Brien, your first answer helped fixed the problem anyways, appreciate your time.